# Error on Upsert Request on Pinecone in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pinecone

## Error: PineconeArgumentError: The argument to upsert had type errors: argument must be array.

Package
"@pinecone-database/pinecone": "^1.0.0",

**Request**

```
const index = pinecone.Index(process.env.PINECONE_INDEX_NAME);
const upsertResponse = await index.upsert(
{
vectors: [
{
id: "vec1",
values: vector,
metadata: {
title: "Hello ",
body: "Welcome to my world",
},
}],
namespace: process.env.PINECONE_NAME_SPACE,
}
);
console.log("upsertResponse: ", upsertResponse);
}
```

I tried to follow the documentation https://www.npmjs.com/package/@pinecone-database/pinecone and tried the exact same syntax but still same error.

Answer (score 0):

Above code works fine.

> `values: vector`
> , check the number of vector values that must match the dimension of the index.
> Ex: if you are using openai embedding model then the dimension should be 1536.

Updated git repo- https://github.com/pinecone-io/pinecone-ts-client/blob/main/README.md